# Find all polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials  $P(X) \in R[X]$   such that   $P(X^2)  =  (X^3+1)\cdot P(X)$

Can someone help me doing this please ? I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: If $D$ be the degree of $P(x)$, then deg($P(x^2))=2D$. Equating the degree of both sides of the equation, we have $$2D=D+3 \implies D=3$$. Now assume $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2 +cx+d$ and compare the coefficients.

Comment: Start out with the way Tavish described. Hint for more: plug in $x=-1$ or $x=1$ to get a divisibility result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $P(X)$ will be cubic.  Now the zeroes of $P(X^2)$ come in additive inverse pairs but there are no such pairs among the (real or non-real) zeroes of $X^3+1$.  So the factor $P(X)$ on the left must have the additive inverse zeroes instead, forcing

$P(X)=a((-X)^3+1)=-a(X^3-1)$

Plugging in this function for $P$ on both sides we need to match only the leading coefficients to find $a=-1$.  The surviving candidate $P(X)=X^3-1$ then works by trial.